# How do I apply a list of functions to a single variable?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to write a function/macro

```
(defun apply-funcs (functions value) ...)
```

so that calling `(apply-funcs (list #'f #'g #'h) x)` will do the equivalent of `(h (g (f x)))`. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want to `reduce` a list of functions over a value.

```
CL-USER> (defun apply-funcs (functions value)
           (reduce (lambda (memo fn) (funcall fn memo))
                   functions :initial-value value))
CL-USER> (apply-funcs 
            (list (lambda (n) (+ 3 n))
                  (lambda (n) (- n 2))
                  (lambda (n) (* 2 n)))
            6)
14
CL-USER>
```

You may know `reduce` as `fold` from other languages. I'm using `funcall` instead of `apply` because of what you've said you want above (`(apply-funcs (list #'f #'g #'h) x) => (h (g (f x)))`). You'd use `apply` if `x` were a list of values, each element of which you wanted to bind to a separate argument. For instance, if you wanted to do something like

```
(apply-funcs 
 (list (lambda (a b c)
         (list (+ a c) (+ b c)))
       (lambda (d e)
         (+ d e)))
 (list 1 2 3))
```

then you'd need `apply` rather than `funcall` in the definition of `apply-funcs`.

Depending on the situation, you might also take the macro route;

```
(defmacro ->> (value &body functions)
  (reduce 
   (lambda (memo fn) `(funcall ,fn ,memo))
   functions :initial-value value))
```

which will do essentially the same thing.

```
CL-USER> (->> 6
           (lambda (n) (+ 3 n))
           (lambda (n) (- n 2))
           (lambda (n) (* 2 n)))

14
CL-USER> (macroexpand
      '(->> 6
        (lambda (n) (+ 3 n))
        (lambda (n) (- n 2))
        (lambda (n) (* 2 n))))

(FUNCALL (LAMBDA (N) (* 2 N))
         (FUNCALL (LAMBDA (N) (- N 2)) 
                  (FUNCALL (LAMBDA (N) (+ 3 N)) 6)))
T
```

Comment: You could avoid explicit creation of a wrapper lambda by specifying `:from-end t`: `(defun apply-functions (functions value) (reduce #'funcall (reverse functions) :from-end t :initial-value value))`.

Comment: @Svante You wouldn't need to `(reverse functions)`, then, right?  Wouldn't it just be `(reduce 'funcall functions :from-end t :initial-value value)`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I understood the question to apply the first function first.

Comment: @Svante Yes, you're right.  I misread the question.  It'd be interesting to find out which ends up being more expensive:  an anonymous function `(lambda (arg f) (funcall f arg))` or reversing the list.  Of course, it would depend on the size of the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defun apply-funcs (functions value)
  (loop for f in functions
        for result = (funcall f value) then (funcall f result)
        finally (return result)))
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Alexandria library comes the `compose` (and `multiple-value-compose`) function, including a compiler macro for `compose`. What you're describing seems analogous to

```
(funcall (alexandria:compose #'h #'g #'f) x)
```

such that

```
(defun apply-funcs (functions value)
   (funcall (apply #'compose (reverse functions)) value))
```

would do what you intend — although I suspect that calling `compose` directly might be more effective for your purposes, depending on the context.

The library functions are:

```
(defun compose (function &rest more-functions)
  "Returns a function composed of FUNCTION and MORE-FUNCTIONS that applies its
arguments to to each in turn, starting from the rightmost of MORE-FUNCTIONS,
and then calling the next one with the primary value of the last."
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 1) (debug 1)))
  (reduce (lambda (f g)
        (let ((f (ensure-function f))
          (g (ensure-function g)))
          (lambda (&rest arguments)
        (declare (dynamic-extent arguments))
        (funcall f (apply g arguments)))))
          more-functions
          :initial-value function))

(define-compiler-macro compose (function &rest more-functions)
  (labels ((compose-1 (funs)
             (if (cdr funs)
                 `(funcall ,(car funs) ,(compose-1 (cdr funs)))
                 `(apply ,(car funs) arguments))))
    (let* ((args (cons function more-functions))
           (funs (make-gensym-list (length args) "COMPOSE")))
      `(let ,(loop for f in funs for arg in args
           collect `(,f (ensure-function ,arg)))
         (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 1) (debug 1)))
         (lambda (&rest arguments)
           (declare (dynamic-extent arguments))
           ,(compose-1 funs))))))
```